# How java PDFBox check whether certificate is registered in AATL or EUTL

Tags: java, certificate, pdfbox, digital-signature, aatl

For enabling LTV while digitally signing the document, we should also verify whether the certificate (used for signing) is registered in AATL (Adobe Approved Trust List) or EUTL (European Union Trust List) or not. How we can verify this using java Apache PDFBox.

When I opened the LTV enabled document (generated using PDFBox) in Adobe Acrobat it is already coming that the "Source of trust is obtained from Adobe Approved Trust List". But how I can verify the same using java PDFBox. Is it already performed internally in PDFBox?

Comment: PDFBox does not retrieve or parse Adobe trust lists. You can retrieve and parse the TLs yourself, use PDFBox to parse and cryptographically validate the signatures, and then check the certificates found by PDFBox against the TLs you have.

Comment: @mkl Any way to retrieve the list of Adobe's trust list? Couldn't find much info regarding this exception this stackoverflow question.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/vargaviktor/aatleutlparser